# How to cut "extra" lines in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, clipping-mask

Please tell me how do I get rid of redundant lines in illustrator?

I covered them up using a clipping mask, but when I go into *Outline Mode* I can still see/modify them. I'd like to get rid of them.

[image: Here's my final work]

[image: These are the extra lines as seen in outline mode]

Comment: I am guessing you are asking how to remove the lines/content that are outside your clipping mask?

Answer (score 3):

First, you may need a pathfinder. Which can be found on *Window > Pathfinder*.

Then do the following:

1. Select the lines that you may need to cut it out, and then do *Pathfinders > Outline*.

[image: First Picture]

(optional)2a. You may ungroup them, to select each individuals.

[image: Second Picture]

2b. Now, you can select the following excess lines by using any selection tool you like. I prefer, the main selection tool. Although, you may use direct selection tool, which I use it here, and remove them.

[image]

(optional)3a. If you are doing the 2a. You may need to select them again, and regroup them. Together.

[image]